# Rails includes vs all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am going back to refresh my Rails knowledge by watching some tutorials, and I came across where the tutorial rails app uses `includes()` on `index`.

```
  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end
```

vs

```
  def index
    @books = Book.includes(:author, :genre)
  end
```

As a side note, book `belongs_to` author and genre. Author `has_many` books and genre also `has_many` books.

When `all` is used, it looks like this when I refresh page:

```
 Rendering books/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Book Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
  Author Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Author Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When `includes` is used, when I reload the page it shows:

```
  Rendering books/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
  Author Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" IN (2, 1)
  Genre Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" IN (2, 3)
```

I think this makes includes far more efficient than all because it hits the entire model database.

My question is, why do people still use `all`? Why not completely eradicate `all` and use includes from now on? Is there any situation where I would prefer to use all and not use includes? I am using Rails 5.0.1.

Comment: `includes` is based on relationships in the model, book probably `belongs_to` author here, if there is no relationship between the objects then using `.all` would be what you want I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Let me talk a little bit about `includes`.

Suppose you need to get the user name of first five post. You quickly write the query below and go enjoy your weekend.

```
posts = Post.limit(5)

posts.each do |post|
  puts post.user.name
end
```

Good. But let's look at the queries

```
Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

`1 query` to fetch all `posts` and `1 query` to fetch `users` for each post results in a total of `6 queries`. Check out the solution below which does the same thing, just in `2 queries`:

```
posts = Post.includes(:user).limit(5)

posts.each do |post|
  puts post.user.name
end

#####

Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2)
```

There’s one little difference. Add `includes(:posts)` to your query, and problem solved. Quick, nice, and easy.

But don’t just add `includes` in your query without understanding it properly. Using `includes` with `joins` might result in cross-joins depending on the situation, and you don’t need that in most cases.

**If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to explicitly reference them**. For example:

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')
```

Will throw an error, but this will work:

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)
```

Note that `includes` works with `association names` while `references` needs `the actual table name`.